# Moving character in given direction C++ SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I have written simple input manager which is used for me to detect key press, and fire assigned function. For example I can do something like that:

```
auto own_pointer = std::make_shared<Player>(*this);
inputControl.addKeyToCheck( sf::Keyboard::H, std::function<void( Player& )>( &Player::sayHello ),own_pointer );
```

and in my loop manager, I check input managers, and if H is pressed, then function `sayHello` will be fired.

I have written moving my player with this input manager.

```
auto own_pointer = std::make_shared<Player>(*this);
inputControl.addKeyToCheck( sf::Keyboard::A, std::function<void( Player& )>( &Player::moveLeft ),own_pointer );
inputControl.addKeyToCheck( sf::Keyboard::D, std::function<void( Player& )>( &Player::moveRight ), own_pointer );
inputControl.addKeyToCheck( sf::Keyboard::S, std::function<void( Player& )>( &Player::moveDown ), own_pointer );
inputControl.addKeyToCheck( sf::Keyboard::W, std::function<void( Player& )>( &Player::moveTop ), own_pointer );
```

where for example `moveTop` is just

```
void Player::moveTop()
{
    this->getComponent<Velocity>()->y -= speed * mv::constants::mob::DEFAULT_SPEED;
}
```

Generally I am so proud of my `InputManager`, it works everywhere else but there is really bad to use 4 different function to control moving. Have somebody any advice how to deal with that style problem?

### Input manager

```
    /**
    * @brief Class which manage keys' input
    */
    template <class T>
    class InputManager
    {
        /* ===Objects=== */
    public:
    protected:
    private:
        //when you press KEY you execute FunctionWrapper
        std::map < sf::Keyboard::Key, FunctionPointerWrapper_t<T>> keyData;
        /* ===Methods=== */
    public:
        /**
        * @brief Checks if keys have been clicked
        */
        void update();

        /**
        * @bried adds key to database
        */
        bool addKeyToCheck( sf::Keyboard::Key key, std::function<void( T& )> function, std::shared_ptr<T> object );

        /**
        * @brief remove key from database
        */
        bool eraseKey( sf::Keyboard::Key key );
    protected:
    private:
    };

    template <class T>
    void InputManager<T>::update()
    {
        for ( auto&var : keyData )
            if ( sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed( var.first ) )
                var.second.function( *var.second.object );
    }

    template <class T>
    bool InputManager<T>::addKeyToCheck( sf::Keyboard::Key key, std::function<void( T& )> function, std::shared_ptr<T> object )
    {
        keyData.emplace( key, FunctionPointerWrapper_t<T>( function, object ) );

        return true;
    }

    template <class T>
    bool InputManager<T>::eraseKey( sf::Keyboard::Key key )
    {
        keyData.erase( key );
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure this question is a good fit for CodeReview. If you posted the input manager class we could suggest general improvements, some of which might cover what you're asking. However, for a specific question like this you might have better luck on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: this question is only about style, so I think that it is good. Ok, I am going to edit question

Comment: Can you provide a usage example of how your input manager is invoked and in what manner?

Comment: @Mast it is just invoked by inputManager.update() in main game loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FunctionPointerWrapper_t` seems unnecessary; we can store a `std::function<void()>` in the map directly. To create this function, we can either use [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

```
auto player = std::make_shared<Player>(*this);
inputControl.addKeyToCheck( sf::Keyboard::H, std::bind(&Player::sayHello, player) );
```

or a [lambda function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
auto player = std::make_shared<Player>(*this);
inputControl.addKeyToCheck( sf::Keyboard::H, [=] () { player->sayHello(); } );
```

Note that both of these examples internally create a copy of the `shared_ptr`.

---

For cutting down on the number of named functions in the player class, we can route the functionality to a single `move` function, something like:

```
void Player::move(Vector2f const& speed) { getComponent<Velocity>() += speed * mv::constants::mob::DEFAULT_SPEED; }
```

We can then use `std::bind`, or lambda functions as above:

```
inputControl.addKeyToCheck( sf::Keyboard::W, std::bind(&Player::move, player, Vector2f(0.f, -1.f)) );
inputControl.addKeyToCheck( sf::Keyboard::W, [=] () { player->move(Vector2f(0.f, -1.f)); });
```

Where `Vector2f(0.f, -1.f)` can be replaced by whatever the actual desired type / value is. (We could also do the multiplication outside of the move function, if it's not common between the functions).

We still need to define 4 functions, but there's less overhead in the `Player` class.

To simplify it further, we'd probably want to define some sort of axis mapping, so we could do something like:

```
inputControl.addAxis(Axis(sf::Keyboard::W, sf::Keyboard::S, maxSpeed, minSpeed), [=] (float axisValue) { player->moveVertically(axisValue); });
```

(and perhaps even allow a 2d-axis to be defined mapping 4 keys to one function call) but that might be a fair amount of extra work.

---

General comments:

- `InputManager::addKeyToCheck` and `InputManager::eraseKey` should probably not return a fixed `true` / `false` without checking if they actually succeeded.